# Using self to get variables within a class?

Tags: self, getter-setter

This is probably a silly question, but if i have a variable called, say nstate, defined with appropriate getters and setters within a class, and I would like to get its value from within the class, is it better to use

```
self.nstate
```

or

```
nstate
```

when getting its value within the same class?  Is there an aesthetic benefit?  Is there any difference in performance?

Comment: Please can you tag your question with the appropriate language!

Comment: I think he/she has -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_(programming_language)

Answer (score 0):

If Self is like Java then `nstate` is preferable to `self.nstate` this is because there are less symbols to read, making code quicker to read and comprehend. The more symbols in a line of code the longer it takes to read.

On the other hand the language, if the language is like python then you MUST use `self.nstate` as `nstate` will always refer to the local scope even if `nstate` doesn't exist in the local scope.